How to change the appearance of the TextField in the Django admin?
I want to increase the size of the text area in django admin form.
html_content = models.TextField()

Use the formfield_overrides attribute in your ModelAdmin class to specify a widget for all TextField instances. For example,
class HtmlModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('description', 'enabled')
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 50, 'cols': 150})},
    }

admin.site.register(HtmlModule, HtmlModuleAdmin)

However, this will affect all TextField inputs for this particular model in the admin.

You can plug this into a ModelForm and then use that form in the admin, like:
class HtmlModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HtmlModule
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'html_content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 50, 'cols': 150})
        }
and plug this in in the ModelAdmin:
class HtmlModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = HtmlModuleForm


admin.site.register(HtmlModule, HtmlModuleAdmin)
